# How to make an animation fully complete on a key press for phaser.io

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So I've looked through a few videos, some websites that posed the same question, and even phaser.io's own example codes and I'm still stuck on not being able to get an animation to fully complete on a key press. I think I have phaser 2.4.4, our professor required it. The animation isn't the only thing going on while the key is pressed though. I call another function to do something (teleport the character). I toyed around with the time.events stuff all day, but no luck. The way I want it to all work out is to play the animation when the key is pressed, make the character invisible, then have the character reappear at the new location, coming in with the same teleport animation. The function I have already deals with the actual teleporting for the most part, it's just the animation that doesn't play fully. It only plays while I'm holding down the corresponding buttons, and then stops when I let go. When looking through the other sites one of them said to do .isPressed() for a similar issue, but the game screen just turns black if I try using that. Here's my messy and stress-ridden code so y'all can help me hopefully. I'm just gonna include most of update because there could be something in there that's messing with something else. Plus the other 3 associated methods.

```js
    //Inside create
    blinkAni = knight.animations.add('teleport', [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 14);
    blinkAni.onComplete.add(blinkTele, this);
    
    canBlink = true;
}
    
function update(){
    var hitPlatform = game.physics.arcade.collide(knight, platforms);

    //------------------MOVEMENT--------------------------//

    //Teleport
    if (blink.isDown &&//These for blinking in current direction
        (moveBinds.leftA.isDown || moveBinds.rightD.isDown || moveBinds.upW.isDown || moveBinds.downS.isDown)) {
        knight.animations.play('teleport');
        
//        if(canBlink){
//            blinkTele();
//            canBlink = false;
//        }
    } else if (game.input.activePointer.leftButton.isDown) {
        knight.animations.play('teleport');
        if(canTele){
            cursorTele();
            //canTele = false;
        }
    }
    //Attack
    else if (attack.isDown) {
        knight.animations.play('attack');
    }
    //Move Left and Right
    else if (moveBinds.leftA.isDown) {
        knight.body.velocity.x = -400;
        knight.scale.setTo(-1, 1); //Knight faces left
        knight.animations.play('walk');
    } else if (moveBinds.rightD.isDown) {
        knight.body.velocity.x = 400;
        knight.scale.setTo(1, 1); //Knight faces right
        knight.animations.play('walk');
    } else {
        knight.animations.play('stand');
    }

    //Jump ------------NEEDS FIXING: touching.down->->->->Only works with actual ground and platforms, not world bounds. So make ground and //platform objects
    if (moveBinds.upW.isDown && knight.body.touching.down) {
        knight.body.velocity.y = -300;
    }

    //Stop moving left/right ------------NEEDS FIXING: touching.down->->->->->Ditto^^^
    if (moveBinds.downS.isDown && knight.body.touching.down) {
        knight.body.velocity.x = 0;
    }

    // Horizontal momentum kept and slowed down with drag
    speed = knight.body.velocity.x;
    if (speed > 0) {
        knight.body.velocity.x = Math.abs(speed - drag);
    } else if (speed < 0) {
        knight.body.velocity.x = speed + drag;
    } else {
        knight.body.velocity.x = 0;
    }
    //------------------END MOVEMENT--------------------------//
}

//Long teleportation
function cursorTele() {
    //In order to make it to where the knight's center/midpoint is wherever the mouse clicks, calculations are needed
    //if() facing right
    var newX = game.input.activePointer.x - knight.body.width/4;
    //^^With current spritesheet this is what has to be done in order to center width-wise^^
    var newY = game.input.activePointer.y - knight.body.height/2;
    //to prevent getting stuck in ground
    if (newY >= game.world.height - antiGroundStuck) {
        newY = game.world.height - antiGroundStuck;
    }
    teleport(newX, newY);
}


//Blink
function blinkTele(sprite, animation) {
    var newX = knight.body.x;
    var newY = knight.body.y;
    //if moving right add 10 to current pos
    if (moveBinds.rightD.isDown) {
        newX += blinkDist;
    }
    //else subtract 10
    else if (moveBinds.leftA.isDown) {
        newX -= blinkDist;
    }

    //if moving up subtract 10 to current pos
    else if (moveBinds.upW.isDown) {
        newY -= blinkDist;
    }
    //else add 10
    else if (moveBinds.downS.isDown) {
        newY += blinkDist;
        //check to not go below ground. Account for height of world and height of ground
        if (newY >= game.world.height - antiGroundStuck)
            newY = game.world.height - antiGroundStuck; //above or exactly at ground height
    }

    //        blinkTick--;

    //reset timer and tick if out of ticks
    //if(){
    //knight.body.y = 300;
    //            this.blinkTimer.destroy();
    //            blinkTimer = game.time.create(false);
    //            blinkTimer.start();
    //            blinkTick = 5;
    //      }
    teleport(newX, newY);
}

//Teleport
function teleport(newX, newY) {
    knight.body.x = newX;
    knight.body.y = newY;
    //Make teleporting look like actual teleporting
    knight.visibile = false;
    game.time.events.add(Phaser.Time.SECOND, this);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've been struggling literally all day with this :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure this will answer your question, but it'll be far too long for just a comment:

1. There are a number of places where you're calling the `update()` directly. For example, `game.time.events.add(Phaser.Time.SECOND, update, this);` and `game.time.events.add(Phaser.Time.SECOND * 5, update, this);`. Assuming it's setup properly, `update` will automatically get called by Phaser, and there's no need to call it yourself. This is likely causing issues.
2. When defining the animations, you can also define what will happen when they complete, or loop. See the official documentation for [`onComplete`](https://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Animation.html#onComplete) and [`onLoop`](https://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Animation.html#onLoop). See also the [Animation Events example](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/animation/animation-events) for a usage example. This would be better than, for example, the below:

   ```
   knight.animations.play('teleport', 7, true);
   knight.visibile = false;
   game.time.events.add(4000, blinkTele, this);
   //canBlink = false;
   ```

You should then be able to chain these together to do what you'd like.

### Update

Here's a short working example using Phaser 2.4.4:

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', {
 preload: preload, create: create, update: update
});

function preload() {
 this.load.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
 game.load.image('sky', 'https://jamesskemp.github.io/PhaserTutorials/Official-Making-A-Game/assets/sky.png');
 game.load.image('platform', 'https://jamesskemp.github.io/PhaserTutorials/Official-Making-A-Game/assets/platform.png');
 game.load.spritesheet('dude', 'https://jamesskemp.github.io/PhaserTutorials/Official-Making-A-Game/assets/dude.png', 32, 48);
}

var platforms;
var player;
var cursors;

var leftAnimation;
var rightAnimation;
var canMove = true;

function create() {
 // Enable arcade physics.
 game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

 // Background image.
 game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'sky');

 // Includes ground and the ledges.
 platforms = game.add.group();

 // Enable physics for all objects in this group.
 platforms.enableBody = true;

 // Create the ground.
 var ground = platforms.create(0, game.world.height - 64, 'platform');

 // Scale the image to fit the width of the game.
 ground.scale.setTo(2, 2);

 // Ground is solid and doesn't move.
 ground.body.immovable = true;

 // Create the player.
 player = game.add.sprite(32, game.world.height - 150, 'dude');

 // Enable physics on the player.
 game.physics.arcade.enable(player);
 player.body.bounce.y = 0.2;
 player.body.gravity.y = 300;
 player.body.collideWorldBounds = true;

 // Player has walk animations, at 10 frames per second.
 leftAnimation = player.animations.add('left', [0, 1, 2, 3], 10);
 rightAnimation = player.animations.add('right', [5, 6, 7, 8], 10);

 rightAnimation.onComplete.add(animationComplete, this);
 leftAnimation.onComplete.add(animationComplete, this);

 // Enable keyboard cursor support.
 cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
}

function animationComplete() {
 console.log('animation complete, moving to random location');
 player.x = game.rnd.integerInRange(10, game.world.width - 10);
 canMove = true;
}

function update() {
 // The player and platforms should collide.
 game.physics.arcade.collide(player, platforms);

 // Reset the player's velocity.
 player.body.velocity.x = 0;

 if (canMove) {
  if (cursors.left.isDown) {
   canMove = false;
   // Move to the left.
   player.body.velocity.x = -150;
   player.animations.play('left');
  } else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
   canMove = false;
   // Move to the right.
   player.body.velocity.x = 150;
   player.animations.play('right');
  }
 }

 // Player can jump if they're touching ground.
 if (cursors.up.isDown && player.body.touching.down) {
  player.body.velocity.y = -350;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/2.4.4/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

Unfortunately there's enough unknown variables that I can't replicate your example to test my theories, but I would try setting a variable when you start the teleportation animation and check for it in `update`. I would try wrapping your entire movement logic initially.

`onComplete` will only trigger if the animation completes, which it won't do if another animation starts, such as your last `else` where `knight.animations.play('stand');` runs.

Comment: Thank you! I tried using what you gave and looked at the example, but using the onComplete or onLoop neither plays the animation (besides showing the first frame) nor calls the function. I tried using onStart just to see what it would do, and that managed to call the function but it stays stuck on the first frame of the animation. I got rid of the update calls, they didn't seem to change much but hopefully that fixed something.

Comment: Would you mind updating your question with what you've changed it to? I think you would be safe replacing your code instead of adding it as another block, but I'll defer to you on what's better. Second, using `onComplete` and `onLoop` won't actually play the animation, it will just bind whatever functionality you define there to those events. You'll still want to `play` the animation.

Comment: I updated the code snippet, leaving out some things that I didn't think were relevant to the problem. Anyways, I tried making a blinkAni variable that I could set the onComplete event thing to, and I played it inside the update function when a few buttons are pressed. The animation plays to how I have it set up in the blink if statement, but my blinkTele function isn't called.

Comment: I've updated my answer with working example, and some additional suggestions.